# SurveyMonkey privacy link

Tags: policy, privacy, surveymonkey

I have noticed a new error that has just started coming back from SurveyMonkey:

RESPONSE MESSAGE:s:253:"{"error": {"id": "1002", "name": "Bad Request", "docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes", "message": "Your message is missing the privacy link ([PrivacyLink] or {{PrivacyLink}}). This data is required.", "http_status_code": 400}}";

I'm not sure what this is or why I am getting it all of a sudden. I can't find anything on their api developer documentation. Is this something new? Is this something rolled out without any notification?

Any point in the right direction would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your body text param should look something like

```
"body_text": "Thank you in advance for taking my survey. [SurveyLink], [PrivacyLink], [OptOutLink], [FooterLink]"
```

just make sure you include this `[PrivacyLink]` and you should be good!